# Div occupying total space of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like other pages, the main div is always a way in which occupies the entire screen seen by the User, and when he scroll down he can see another div: [example1](http://wordpress.metaphorcreations.com/apex/) , [example2](https://www.snapchat.com/)

No matter if you resize the screen, the main div will always occupy the total space seen by the User.

To test It I try this code below:

```
<div style="background:yellow;  position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1; float:left;">
    This is my Section!
</div>
```

With him I can see a large yellow background with a text occupying the entire area of my browser. Assuming I would like to add another div below this, how could I do that? Is possible with css or I will need javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it **without** javascript with only pure CSS.

With `vh` units, you can specify a `margin-top` on the next container like this :

```
#content { margin-top: 100vh;}
```

The advantage of this method is that it is **fully** responsive, no matter how you resize it (height or width).

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksLjtggy/1/)

Comment: You're welcome ! mark the subject as solved if it's ok for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check your `div` more correctly, this code:

```
top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

Is what causes your `div` to occupy the whole screen because there isn't any space between the div since you set all of them at 0.